# CSS way to restrict line break for text

Tags: html, css

I have maybe a little bit strange task, but I belive there is no better solution. I need to have `<ul>` in some container which width is changeable and with inlined `<li>` elements of fixed width. I should (and already found solution) put spaces between `<li>` elems of same width. Width of spaces is changes dynamicaly and depends of parental container width. Again, this `<li>` items have fixed width.

I also should place some links above this described elements. For some reasons links must be in other `<ul>` element. They also wrapped in inlined `<li>` elems. And I want them to be positioned right above described `<li>` items. This can be done by setting fixed width of `<li>` items as above. Now, the problem is that text in every link is actualy have different width and will break into two lines, but I must place it into one line.

So I want to trick browser: text will be overflowing `<li>` items.

```
.liElem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

But, as you may guess, text is breaking into two lines and overflowing actually the bottom of list items, not the right side.

The effect I wanted can be done by inserting `&nbsp;` insted of spaces in text like this: `<li><a href="#">Add&nbsp;to&nbsp;Favourites</a></li>` .

So, my question is this: how in css-way make usual text NOT to break into several lines ?

Comment: you have set width : 100px; in your css, so if the line's width is more than 100px it will break the text into several lines, so may be you dont need to set width. or you can use white-space:nowrap; property.

Comment: I must have list items be of fixed width. As I said I want to trick browser, let it think that he will be position elements width fixed width.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
.nobr  { white-space:nowrap; }
```

Comment: thanx! you rock!